# Totally bounded subsets of simple functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there a way to characterize the totally bounded subsets of the space of simple functions on the space, say, $[0,1]$? For the space $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ we have the Arzela-Ascoli theorem and for the space $\mathcal{L}_p[0,1]$ there's the Kolmogorov theorem. I wish to know if such a result exists for the space of simple functions equipped with the uniform metric.

Comment: Total boundedness requires  a mertic. What metric are you using on the space of simple functions?

Comment: I should have mentioned it. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found a possible answer. A subset $\mathcal A$ of simple functions is totally bounded if and only if it is bounded (in the supremum norm) and for any given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite partition $(A_i)_i$ of $[0,1]$ into measurable sets such that  $\forall f\in\mathcal A$ and for each $i$ we have $\vert{f(x)-f(y)}\vert<\epsilon$ a.e. in $A_i$.